# flex-direction row CSS DOM Javascript, set boxes next to eachother in a row. It doesnt work that way

Tags: javascript, css, dom, flexbox, row

A function that takes 2 arguments: amount and color. The function is gonna create as many boxes as amount and in the color that is given in the argument. The boxes shall lay next to eachother in a row. With margin to seperate the boxes.

I have problem to get them in a row. I have tried flex-direction: row but it doesnt seem to work, they just land in top of eachoter like in a column..

Script:

```
function antalFärg(a, f){
        for(let i=0; i< a; i++){
        const div3 = document.createElement('div')
        div3.className = 'div3'
        div3.style.backgroundColor = `${f}`  
        console.log(div3)
        document.body.appendChild(div3)
    }
}
antalFärg(4, 'blue')
```

Css:

```
<style>
        .div3{
            margin: 3px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row; 
            height: 100px; 
            width: 100px; 
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: `display: flex;` wants to be on a parent container, not on each box.

Comment: Please post a working [repro] (`ctrl + M` or `<>`-Button) for debugging details. Your HTML is missing.

Comment: I didnt had any HTML at that point :)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is you have appended it to a body.

Instead, you can create a div and append to it... with basic styles `display: flex; flex-direction: row;`

```js
function antalFärg(a, f) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    const div3 = document.createElement('div')
    div3.className = 'div3'
    div3.style.backgroundColor = `${f}`
    console.log(div3)
    document.getElementById("firstDiv").appendChild(div3)
    // document.body.appendChild(div3)
  }
}
antalFärg(4, 'blue')
```

```css
.firstDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.div3 {
  margin: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="firstDiv" class="firstDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note, that `flex-direction: row` is redundant as it is the default value for that property.

Comment: `Your mistake is you have appended it to a body.`  That's not the reason :), as your snippet shows, you need a container element that you have for some reasons called `firstDiv`..

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But now it doesnt show at all... Are you sure that this worked?